# display different div when click buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I am trying to accomplish a page which has two buttons on the bottom. Clicking each of these buttons will bring out different content.
For example:

```
<div id="page1">...some content...</div>
<div id="page2">...some content...</div>
```

My css:

```
#page1 { display: block;}
#page2 { display: none;}
```

And the buttons are images:

```
<div id="button1"><img src="images/button1.png"/></div>
<div id="button2"><img src="images/button2.png"/></div>
```

I am using javascript to make the buttons work. `#block` is an object that moves when the buttons are clicked:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button1").click(function () {
            $("#block").animate({
                left: "10px"
            });
            $("#page1").attr("display", "block");
            $("#page2").attr("display", "none");
        });
        $("#button2").click(function () {
            $("#block").animate({
                left: "100px"
            });
            $("#page1").attr("display", "none");
            $("#page2").attr("display", "block");
        });
    });
</script>
```

So when `#button1` is clicked:
`#page1` will be changed to `display:block;`
`#page2` will be changed to `display:none;` - hidden

When `#button2` is clicked:
`#page1` will be changed to `display:none;` - hidden
`#page2` will be changed to `display:block;`
This means it will show the content on `page2`

Comment: put together a fiddle with what you have.  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Do some reading on using jquery toggles and using functions as well. It will greatly improve your coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you really should have a css class called page and another called page-invisible.  Then you just do

```
$('#page1').addClass("page-invisible");
$('#page2').removeClass("page-invisible");
```

the class page-invisible just is {display:none}, or it can be something like {opacity:.3; z-index:0} etc to have it kind of "behind" the other one (you would have to set position absolute etc to put the divs on top of eachother.

Comment: thanks. this looks like a good solution when i want to switch between 6 pages and use 6 buttons

Answer (score 3):

`display` is not an attribute, it's a property of the `style` attribute/object. But jQuery has its own show, hide and toggle methods, so you can simply use this:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
      $("#button1").click(function(){
           $("#block").animate({left:"10px"});
           $("#page1, #page2").toggle();
      });
      $("#button2").click(function(){
           $("#block").animate({left:"100px"});
           $("#page1, #page2").toggle(); 
      }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: it seems like toggle() switches between these two classes when i double click a button...is it achievable to adapt this into 6 classes with 6 buttons?

Comment: @BigGirl1017 `toggle()` shows what is hidden, and hides what's shown. Try it with 6 buttons and contents, might be what you're looking for, or not...